# Python dict with lists as values, create list of dicts with all possible combinations of original keys-values

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, python-itertools

I have a dict where all values are lists:

```
original_dict = {"key_00": [0, 1],
                    "key_01": [2, 3]
                    }
```

I want to get a list of dicts, where to each key is associated one of the original corresponding values, forming all the possible combinations...in other words, like this:

```
[
{"key_00": 0, "key_01": 2},
{"key_00": 0, "key_01": 3},
{"key_00": 1, "key_01": 2},
{"key_00": 1, "key_01": 3}
]
```

I tried using something like this:

```
res = []
for combs in product(*original_dict.values()):
    # zip used to perform cross keys combinations.
    res.append([{ele: cnt} for ele, cnt in zip(original_dict, combs)])
```

but this way I end up having

```
[{'key_00': 0}, {'key_01': 2}]
[{'key_00': 0}, {'key_01': 3}]
[{'key_00': 1}, {'key_01': 2}]
[{'key_00': 1}, {'key_01': 3}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`list comprehesntion`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
from itertools import product

original_dict = {"key_00": [0, 1],"key_01": [2, 3]}

res = [{ele: cnt for ele, cnt in zip(original_dict, combs)} 
       for combs in product(*original_dict.values())]

print(res)
```

Your code can fix like below:

```
res = []
for combs in product(*original_dict.values()):
    res.append({ele: cnt for ele, cnt in zip(original_dict, combs)})
```

---

```
[
    {'key_00': 0, 'key_01': 2}, 
    {'key_00': 0, 'key_01': 3}, 
    {'key_00': 1, 'key_01': 2}, 
    {'key_00': 1, 'key_01': 3}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use itertools.product():

```
import itertools
original_dict = {"key_00": [0, 1],
                 "key_01": [2, 3]}

keys, values = zip(*original_dict.items())
aim = [dict(zip(keys, v)) for v in itertools.product(*values)]
print(aim)

>>> [{'key_00': 0, 'key_01': 2},
     {'key_00': 0, 'key_01': 3},
     {'key_00': 1, 'key_01': 2},
     {'key_00': 1, 'key_01': 3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    res.append([{ele: cnt for ele, cnt in zip(original_dict, combs)}])
```